# How can I iterate through a multi lined textbox and asynchronously run LINQ SQL queries for each line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Basically, this is what I want to do.  Imagine a textbox with:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
```

I want to put these into a multi-lined textbox on a ASP .NET page, and have it iterate through these objects and run a LINQ-SQL query on each one.  Basically, the LINQ-SQL query would return the PC's with what software is installed (this might end up in something like an excel spreadsheet but I can work with this once I have the data back).

My challenge is this:  I want to run the query asynchronously, and update the user after each computer has had the LINQ-SQL query run against it (something like Checking Computer2... Checking Computer 3...).  The query is pretty complex, and at the end it has to "add up" all the machines data and put it into a datatable for exporting.

The main thing that has got me stumped is the async for the LINQ SQL, and how to update the user with what computer we are "currently" on.

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: Is it not possible to change the logic of how you are taking ipnut from user? There are many simpler and better options available for doing it.like you can have a dropdown having list of objects with separate add button and below to it may be a small grid view with list of added items and remove button and when object gets selected in dropdown and user clicks on add button for each row then you can use AJAX call to the server to check validity..

Comment: There's going to be thousands of "unique" computers in this.... so the dropdown box might get a bit hectic

Comment: What about ajax? Multiple asynchronous requests initiated client side. BTW especially if there are thousands of computers to pick from...a better ui design may help! I've expect at least filtering and pagination...

Comment: @LewisCianci..In my personal humble opinion ..you need to chnage UI design..may be in dropdown autocomplete option of ..multiple select dropdown like select2 in jquery .. https://select2.github.io/examples.html .. or something better than just a multiline textbox.

Comment: From asking this question I've come to understand I may be a little bit out of my depth in what I'm asking... I'll take a look at those examples though :) Thankyou, I accept your suggestion @SagarShirke, I definitely need to change how I build this.

Answer (score 0):

Executing each of the SQL query lines, you are expecting the results to *stream* as soon as they finish execution. Classic HTTP communication is not well sutied for that type of process (Although possible of course).

I would go about it this way:
- Create a SignalR server
- Post an SQL line to the server and get back a "job ID"
- On the client listen to SignalR callbacks from the server which would push a "job ID" and the results associated with that job.
- As more jobs results are pushed from the server update the UI about the progress, outstanding jobs etc.

Note that you can also post the query lines using SignalR and thus unifying the programming model.

On the server, once a "job" has been submitted, you would want to spin up a Task to handle the query execution. If you want the jobs to be executed in order and serially, you could use a queue of some sort.

Also note that the order in which the responses are streamed to the client is not guaranteed (when executing in parallel) since the first job may run longer then the second job for example.